# AWS Policies for AvailabilityZone

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have been asked to create a Policy and attach this to a role: The policy must do:

1. Describe* everything in AWS
2. Allow Limited access to EC2, e.g. Create instances, create AIM, create snapshot, attach drives etc, However I want this those policies to be attached to this role based on region. All this is to avoid users deleting all EC2 across regions, so if a user delete instances by mistake etc he has authority to delete on that region only..any idea?

thanks

i done it by doing this

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1499242644000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1499243073000",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:TerminateInstances"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-2a"
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The read only policy that AWS provides in the IAM builder may work for you; I needed a few more explicit things, so I put together [a read-only policy for my needs](https://static.quinnadvisory.com/qa-iam-policy.txt).

Unfortunately, you can only restrict per region, not AZ– and not all resources have IAM policies that accept region-specific arguments.

Generally you’re going to have better success by putting the resources in question into a VPC, and then bounding the relevant calls to only operate within that VPC.

Comment: thanks Corey - is That defiantly correct that we cant restrict based on AZ? on IAM?

Comment: Correct. It helps to remember that AZs aren’t consistent between accounts– your us-east-1a could be my us-east-1c. Regions are still consistent.